# Watson SpeechToText Java and javascript model differences

Tags: json, spring-mvc, speech-to-text, ibm-watson

I'm working on integrating the watson-speech.js javascript library with a Spring-based server using the Watson Java SDK.  I'm trying to send the output from a `WatsonSpeech.SpeechToText.recognizeMicrophone` call to the server with no luck. The Speech java classes appear to have the appropriate `@SerializedName` annotations that match the json being sent from the client, but I'm getting `UnrecognizedPropertyException` errors from Jackson.

`Unrecognized field "keywords_result" (class com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.speech_to_text.v1.model.SpeechResults), not marked as ignorable (2 known properties: "resultIndex", "results"])`

Here's the controller method:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/postWatsonRequest", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    @ResponseStatus(value=HttpStatus.OK)
    public ResponseObject postWatsonRequest(@RequestBody SpeechResults speechResults) {
    ...
    }
```

I'm clearly missing something. Do I need to unpack the json manually on the server side (custom deserializer?) or format it into an acceptable json string on the client side?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turned out to be a couple of mistakes on my part and although I'm not sure this is the best solution it does work. Here's the full code for anyone that's interested. Key things that made it work:

- You must use the `receive-jason` event to capture the full json result. The `data` event appears to only return the final text
- The result data had to be wrapped in a valid json wrapper - `data:{message:data}` (this was my big mistake)
- Do not include `contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',` in the ajax call or the controller will not recognize the json data
- The Watson Java SDK `WebSocketManager` receives an `okhttp3.ResponseBody` from Watson from which it extracts a string. I presume this is similar to what the javascript SDK receives so I used the same code from the `WebSocketManager` to convert the JSON.stringify string to a SpeechResults object in the controller.

From the okhttp3.ResponseBody javadoc:

> A one-shot stream from the origin server to the client application with the raw bytes of the response body

**Watson javascript**

```
function listen(token) {
    stream = WatsonSpeech.SpeechToText.recognizeMicrophone({
        token: token,
        readableObjectMode: true,
        objectMode: true,
        word_confidence: true,
        format: false,
        keywords: keywordsArray,
        keywords_threshold : 0.5,
        continuous : false
        //interim_results : false
        //keepMicrophone: navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Firefox') > 0
    });

    stream.setEncoding('utf8');

    stream.on('error', function(err) {
        console.log(err);
        stream.stop();
    });

    stream.on('receive-json', function(msg) {
        console.log(msg);
        if (msg.state != 'listening') {
            if (msg.results[0].final) {
                console.log('receive-json: ' + msg);
                postResults(msg);               
                stream.stop();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

**Ajax post**

```
function postResults(results) {
    var data = JSON.stringify(results);
    console.log('stringify: ' + data);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: appContextPath + '/postWatsonResult',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {message:data}
    })
    .done(function(data) {
        console.log('done data: '+ data);
    })
    .fail(function(jqXHR, status, error) {
        var data = jqXHR.responseJSON;
        console.log('fail data: '+ data);
    });
}
```

**Spring controller**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/postWatsonResult", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
@ResponseStatus(value=HttpStatus.OK)
public ResponseObject postWatsonResult(@RequestParam("message") String message, Locale locale) {
    logger.info("postWatsonRequest");
    JsonObject json = new JsonParser().parse(message).getAsJsonObject();
    SpeechResults results = null;
    if (json.has("results")) {
        results = GSON.fromJson(message, SpeechResults.class);
    }
    if (results != null) {
        logger.debug("results: " + results.getResults().get(0).getAlternatives().get(0).getTranscript());
    }

    return new ResponseObject();
}
```

I still think it should be possible somehow to use `@RequestBody SpeechResults speechResults` so I'll continue to play around with this, but at least I have a working solution.

Comment: @DanielBolanos You're welcome.  I should warn you that I'm still early in the development and very new to Watson so you'll want to play around with this code yourself.  For example, I think the stream.stop() call should maybe be stream.close, but I haven't done enough testing yet.  I also did some playing around with the RequestBody approach and had some limited success, but for now I'm going with what works and may return to that later.

Comment: Thanks LWK69, this will be helpful for other users as well :)